# Magento 2 - How to send e-mail to customer after order payment was successful

Tags: magento2, order-email, magento-2.1.2

How to send e-mail to customer after order payment was successful, right its sending before the success payment. So, disabled the `Order Emails` from Magento back-end, so order emails are stopped. But we need to send email for order confirmation to customer after the payment made (in this case Payumoney). May be through success page email trigger.

Comment: This is usual problem we have seen in Magento 2 raised by lot of users in community, To help this community we have developed this free extension https://magecomp.com/magento-2-order-confirmation-email.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to use event observer. when payment captured status will be change. so you can write code in observer when status become paid(this just example) you will send email.

its depend on module some module give its inbuilt that you can set when to send email to customer. when order placed or when payment received.

hope it will help

Comment: Can you please provide the steps and code if possible...

Comment: Anyone have the solution, please share?

Comment: @Kul : in which observer , we have to put our code.